# ¿Cómo poder recibir fechas a través de CSV con distintos formatos y homogenizarlas al formato que maneja MySQL/MariaDB?

Tags: php, sql, mvc, pdo, mariadb

Actualmente estoy trabajando en PHP con un proyecto web con arquitectura MVC. La tarea principal que se ejerce es la de subir archivos en formato CSV que simplemente contienen un número identificador y una fecha; el problema con el que me estoy encontrando es con el del **formato** de la fecha. El formato de las fechas con las que se está trabajando son los siguientes:

- dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm
- dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm AM/PM

La estructura del archivo CSV que finalmente es recibido por una tabla dentro de mi base de datos, es la siguiente:

| num_empleado | fecha |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 2021-06-01 01:53:00 |
| 1001 | 2021-06-01 05:21:00 |

La cuestión es que al momento de subir el archivo CSV a mi base de datos en MariaDB, el formato que se requiere es el de **aaaa-mm-dd hh:mm** (aunque he visto que también acepta el de **aaaa/mm/dd hh:mm**. Lo que he estado haciendo para solucionar dicho problema es cambiar el formato en el archivo CSV para ajustarlo al que acepta MariaDB antes de subirlo a la base de datos, pero me parecería más práctico para el usuario si dicho cambio de formato se gestionara dentro del código en lugar de que el mismo usuario haga el cambio de formato en el archivo antes de subirlo.

Actualmente tengo la siguiente estructura y métodos que se encargan de recibir el archivo CSV y subirlo a la base de datos:

**VISTA (HTML)**:

```
<form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <fieldset>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="file" name="file" required/>
   </div>
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="importar_archivo" value="IMPORTAR"/>
 </fieldset>

  <?php
     $excel = new ControladorEventos();
     $excel ->ctrImportarExcel();
  ?>

</form>
```

**CONTROLADOR:**

```
static public function ctrImportarExcel()
{
    if(isset($_POST["importar_archivo"])) 
    { 
        $file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; 
        $file_open = fopen($file,"r"); 

        while(($datos = fgetcsv($file_open, 1000, ",")) !== false)
        {
            $no_empleado = $datos[0];
            $fecha = $datos[1]; 

            $tabla = "events";

            $respuesta  = ModeloEventos::mdlImportarExcel($tabla, $datos);
        }

        if($respuesta=="ok")
        {
            echo"<script>
                Swal.fire({ 
                    title: '¡Éxito!',
                    text: 'Importe exitoso',
                    icon: 'success',
                    confirmButtonText:'Entendido'
                    }).then((result)=>{
                        if(result.value){
                            window.location = 'checadas';
                        }
                    });
            </script>";
                
        }
        else
        {
            echo"<script>
                    Swal.fire({ 
                        title: '¡Error!',
                        text: 'Algo salió mal',
                        icon: 'error',
                        confirmButtonText:'Entendido'
                        });
                 </script>";
        }
    }
}
```

**MODELO:**

```
<?php
    require_once "conexion.php";
    class ModeloEventos{

    //Importación de archivo CSV con checadas a la base de datos

    static public function mdlImportarExcel($tabla,$datos)
    {
        $stmt = conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(no_empleado,start_event) VALUES(:no_empleado,:start_event)");
            
        $stmt->bindparam(":no_empleado",$datos[0],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindparam(":start_event",$datos[1],PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            return "ok";
        }else{
            return "error";
        }

        $stmt ->close();
        $stmt = null;
    } 
?>
```

¿Cómo podría adaptar mi controlador para que al recibir el archivo CSV, las fechas se cambien al formato que acepta MariaDB? He intentado de la siguiente forma sin éxito:

`$datos[1] = date_format($datos[1], 'Y-m-d H:i:s');`

De antemano, gracias.

Comment: necesitas validar que es un formato de fecha; luego convertirlo a un objeto de fecha; luego formatearlo a la fecha de Mysql/DBMaria y utilizarlo en tu insert ....

Comment: tambien necesitas tener por lo mínimo idea de como estarán formadas esas fechas o string... no puedes dejar algo así abierto ..

Comment: si el csv tiene problemas con los formatos de fechas y cambian; deberías de leer el csv y manipularlo en ram para después insertar los datos correctamente ... que tan grande es este archivo???

Comment: la otra alternativa es volcar el csv a una tabla temporal y mediante php y el script que te pase volar los datos de un lado al otro ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**En tu controlador debes pasar `$datos[1]` y `$fecha` por los siguientes Métodos/Manejadores de formato.**

**Punto #1**

ok, como te decía en los comentario debes validar que las fechas cumplan con el formato, para eso yo implementaría la siguiente verificación doble (usare dos fechas diferentes en el formato de hora):

```
<?php

//formatos:
//dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm = d/m/Y H:i
//dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm AM/PM = d/m/Y h:i A

function validateDate($date)
{
    $d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i A', $date);
    $d2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $date);
    
    return (($d1 && $d1->format('d/m/Y h:i A') === $date) || ($d2 && $d2->format('d/m/Y H:i') === $date));
    
}

$date1 = '10/10/1999 20:40';
$date2 = '09/09/2010 08:40 PM';

var_dump(validateDate($date1));
var_dump(validateDate($date2));
```

**Output:**

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

**Punto #2**
lo siguiente seria la conversión y la implementación de la validación (usare dos fechas diferentes en el formato de hora):

```php
function formatDate($date){
    return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
}


if(validateDate($date1)){
    var_dump(formatDate($date1)); //fecha en formato DateTime para Base de Datos.
}

if(validateDate($date2)){
    var_dump(formatDate($date2)); //fecha en formato DateTime para Base de Datos.
}
```

**Output:**

```
//observa que los dos dicen 20:40:00 Horas
string(19) "1999-10-10 20:40:00" 
string(19) "2010-09-09 20:40:00"
```

***Documentacion relacionada:***
[DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php)
[DateTime::createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php) 
[strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strtotime.php) 
[date](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)

Comment: Si utilizo una variable **$fecha** con una fecha fija en string (por ejemplo, $fecha = '01/09/2015 12:31'), funciona excelente lo que propones; sin embargo, al enviar la fecha con el valor contenido en la posición 1 del arreglo (por ejemplo, $fecha = $datos[1]), llega una fecha vacía a la base de datos. ¿Alguna idea de por qué suceda esto?

Comment: perdona fijate si hay algun error de sintaxis ya que es ***$datos*** y yo coloque por error **$dato** sin la "s".

Comment: Sí noté el cambio que hiciste y lo corregí, entonces no creo que se trate de sintaxis, lo revisé

Comment: ok puedes hacer un var_dumo de $datos quiero ver que contiene tu array ... use esa estructura ya que indicaste que hay estaba la fecha.

Comment: «string(16) "01/09/2015 12:31" string(16) "01/09/2015 12:31" string(16) "01/09/2015 12:35" string(16)...» y así sucesivamente, son cientos de fechas las que se manejan a través del arreglo.

Comment: me parece que si hay algo mal esta de lado del array como dices; mi solución funciona correctamente con un string el problema esta al generar el array...

Comment: y los datos que das sobre ese tema sin muy pocos... tu POST no incluye ningún ejemplo del array.

Comment: tampoco queda claro por que $datos tiene tantos campos de fecha en tu ejemplo solo lo usas para hacer bind param de nodo empleado y de una fecha: `$stmt->bindparam(":no_empleado",$datos[0],PDO::PARAM_STR);` y 
        `$stmt->bindparam(":start_event",$datos[1],PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: El ejemplo tiene como propósito mostrar el funcionamiento del proyecto y se trata de subir archivos CSV que contienen **número de empleado** y **fecha** (ambos datos separados por comas dada la naturaleza de los archivos CSV); el usuario puede subir un archivo que contenga tan sólo una fecha como uno que contenga cientos. No es algo estático o preestablecido, sino que dependerá del archivo CSV que se suba y la cantidad de datos que contenga. Con el ciclo *while* se gestiona dicha parte, ya que mientras se encuentren datos dentro del archivo, el ciclo se seguirá ejecutando

Comment: El arreglo toma los datos del archivo CSV que se está importando; en la VISTA (HTML) hay una etiqueta *input* de tipo *file* que tiene como nombre **importar_archivo** y ahí se recoge la información del archivo CSV.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131499/discussion-between-arcanis-the-omnipotent-and-jorge-duran).