# Evaluar Múltiples formatos de fechas en un solo método

Tags: php7, date, datetime, refactoring

## Introducción:

Hola Chicos; tengo una idea que no se como llevarla a código.

He creado un validador de formatos de fechas para una [respuesta que he dado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/496849/46896) y he pensando tambien en implementarla en algunos desarrollos que utilizan datos de marcación de reloj y me parece que la respuesta que he dado si bien resuelve el problema no es escalable y que puede ser mejorado:

este es el código del validador, valida únicamente 2 formatos:

```
function validateDate($date)
{
    $d1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i A', $date);
    $d2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $date);
    
    return (($d1 && $d1->format('d/m/Y h:i A') === $date) || ($d2 && $d2->format('d/m/Y H:i') === $date));
    
}
```

## Planteamiento:

El problema que planteo es que quisiera en lugar de validar en el `return`, si cumple con cualquier de los formatos que los formatos los lea desde un array y mediante un argumento evaluar si cumple con los formatos:

*Ejemplo del array de formatos*

```
$format_array =[
    'A'=>'d/m/Y h:i A',
    'B'=>'d/m/Y H:i',
    'C'=>'d/m/Y h:i:s A',
    'D'=>'d/m/Y H:i:S',

    'E'=>'d-m-Y h:i A',
    'F'=>'d-m-Y H:i',
    'G'=>'d-m-Y h:i:s A',
    'H'=>'d-m-Y H:i:S'
];
```

***Lo que esperaba hacer era algo parecido a lo siguiente,
para el argumento pasado `$format`:***

- el formato puede ser una matriz (validar formatos A y B se pasaría  `['A','B']`)
- o una cadena (validar formatos A Únicamente se pasaría 'A')
- o el valor predeterminado es verdadero, no se pasaría nada y true indica que se deben evaluar todos los formatos.

```
    function validateDate($date,$format=true) // 
    {
        // Que se Implementaría 
        // esto no es funcional o escalable:
        return (($d1 && $d1->format('d/m/Y h:i A') === $date) || ($d2 && $d2->format('d/m/Y H:i') === $date));
    
    }
```

## Investigación y Avances:

Quedando algo como:

```
function validateDate($date,$format=true) // 
{

    //formatos escalables y seleccionables a validar.
    $format_array =[
        'A'=>'d/m/Y h:i A',
        'B'=>'d/m/Y H:i',
        'C'=>'d/m/Y h:i:s A',
        'D'=>'d/m/Y H:i:S',
    
        'E'=>'d-m-Y h:i A',
        'F'=>'d-m-Y H:i',
        'G'=>'d-m-Y h:i:s A',
        'H'=>'d-m-Y H:i:S'
    ];

    //Evaluación del argumento formato.
    if(is_string($formmat)){

        $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format_array[$format], $date);
        return ($d && $d->format($format_array[$format]) === $date);

    } else if($format==true || is_array($format)){

        $val= false;
        //Análisis de formatos Múltiples.
        //si es true como valido todo.
        //si es un array validar solo los Formatos en el array.
        return $val;

    }
}
```

la idea es que en lugar de implementar una serie de análisis ternarios o validadores en el `return` iterar y validar los formatos desde un recursos array/objeto de formatos.

## Problema:

*El problema o que me hace falta es poder evaluar el caso de múltiples formatos, no se que utilizar? me parece que implementar `array_map`, `array_walk`, `array_reduce` seria la via para solucionarlo pero no se como implementarlos y ***que logren retornar el bolean*** de:

`$d && $d->format($format_array[$format]) === $date`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de un tiempo he creado este script el cual mas adelante estare llevandola a una libreria/paquete para su distribucion:

***la Clase:***

Esta clase tiene formatos de fechas pre-establecidos pero tambien permite agregarle un formato adicional.

adicional puede validar si la fecha dada corresponde a algunos de los formatos y puede convertir tambien una fecha a un formato estandar...

```php
<?php

class DateManager
{

    private const FORMATS = [
        'A' => 'd/m/Y h:i A',
        'B' => 'd/m/Y H:i',
        'C' => 'd/m/Y h:i:s A',
        'D' => 'd/m/Y H:i:S',
        'E' => 'd-m-Y h:i A',
        'F' => 'd-m-Y H:i',
        'G' => 'd-m-Y h:i:s A',
        'H' => 'd-m-Y H:i:S',
    ];

    public array $new_format = [];

    /**
     * @param string $new_format
     */
    public function setNewFormat(string $new_format): void
    {
        $this->new_format[] = $new_format;
    }

    public function getFormats(): array
    {
        return $this::FORMATS;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getNewFormat(): array
    {
        return $this->new_format;
    }



    public function addFormat(string $pattern){
        try{
            if(date($pattern, strtotime('2011-01-07'))!==false && !in_array($pattern,$this->getFormats(),true)){
                $this->setNewFormat($pattern);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function ValidateDate(string $date) : bool
    {
        foreach(array_merge($this->getFormats(),$this->getNewFormat()) as $key => $pattern){

           $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($pattern, $date);
           if($d && $d->format($pattern) === $date){
               return true;
           }
        }
        return false;
    }

    function FormatDate($date){
        return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
    }

}
```

***Pruebas:***

```php
<?php

$f = new DateManager();

//Analisis de string y formatos de fechas principales:

var_dump($f->ValidateDate('10/10/1999 20:40'));
echo '<br>';
var_dump($f->ValidateDate('09/09/2010 08:40 PM'));
echo '<br>';

//Analisis (Validacion) y Conversion de formato de Fecha:
echo 'Fecha Correcta->10/10/1999 20:40 a: ';
if($f->ValidateDate('10/10/1999 20:40')){
    var_dump($f->FormatDate('10/10/1999 20:40'));
}

echo '<br>';
echo 'Fecha Correcta->09/09/2010 08:40 PM a: ';
if($f->ValidateDate('09/09/2010 08:40 PM')){
    var_dump($f->FormatDate('09/09/2010 08:40 PM'));
}

echo '<br>';
echo 'Fecha Incorrecta->09/XX/2010 0N:40 PM a: ';
if($f->ValidateDate('09/XX/2010 0N:40 PM')){
    var_dump($f->FormatDate('09/XX/2010 0N:40 PM'));
}else{
    echo 'Formato no soportado';
}

echo '<br>';
echo 'Fecha Incorrecta->09--09--2010 20%40 a: ';
if($f->ValidateDate('09--09--2010 20%40')){
    var_dump($f->FormatDate('09--09--2010 20%40'));
}else{
    echo 'Formato no soportado';
}

//Insertando un formato distinto al analisis para darle soporte  en la valisacion:
echo '<br>';
echo 'Fecha formato nuevo d--m--Y H%i -> : ';
var_dump($f->addFormat('d--m--Y H%i')->ValidateDate('09--09--2010 20%40'));
```

***output:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pense en implementar uno de los metodo de recorrido de array pero un foreach hace lo mismo y mas rapido...